# How to play videos in nintendo 3ds browser which does not support HTML5 or flash?

Tags: javascript, video, mobile, browser, video-player

How can I play videos in a webpage in the Nintendo 3DS Browser?

It does not support any kind of video playing plugin.

Could some JavaScript load still images or GIF files in a row to simulate a video playing?

Comment: There is no HTML5 audio support in the 3DS browser according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Browser_(Nintendo_3DS), so even with some super hacky way to create an mjpeg player of super low quality videos, it's impossible to have audio.

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML5 audio support in the 3DS browser according to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Browser_(Nintendo_3DS), so even with some super hacky way to create an mjpeg player of super low quality videos, it's impossible to have audio.
If you're interested in just the video part, without any audio, I think that gif is the only reasonable approach. All will be super low quality though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GIF for the video and `<object data="sound.mp3"></object>` for the sound. Not sure if it'll work but try it. Object is HTML4 and it will use the device's default application to open any file (e.g. flash but 3DS doesn't support that as you said), it's not HTML5, so it might work but I can't test it.